# Is there a Java replacement for CFHTTP to use NTLM Authentication from ColdFusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, ntlm

Facts

1. I need to access a web service protected by NTLM authentication.
2. I am using Coldfusion 8.
3. I need this solution to be cross platform, ex. Windows, Linux, OS-X (aka no .NET component)
4. Java seems to be the way to go, but I cannot wrap my head around the limited advice available online.

Given

1. URL: "http://webservice.com/EndPoint.asmx"
2. Method: POST
3. Username: "UN"
4. Password: "PW"
5. Body: "name=bob&email=bob@bob.bob"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but it may be helpful for those who wanted to know from which version coldfusion cfhttp supports ntlm authentication.

If you take a look at the cfhttp Coldfusion 11 documentation

> Added support for NTLM authentication. Three attributes added -
>   authType, domain, and workstation

ColdFusion 11 cfhttp now supports NTLM authentication. That's good news!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is one based on Apache's HTTP client components.

http://ntlmhttpclient.riaforge.org/

It does support a POST method and NTLM authentication.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, but I am always getting a "401.1 Access is denied due to invalid credentials". It worked fine from windows and the .NET NetHttpRequest.dll. All I can think of is, I use no domain. But looking at the java source that should not be a problem.

Comment: I would say that domain IS important - at least it is with most authentication protocols. Try it and see.

Comment: No, I meant that I don't pass a domain.

Comment: I have some more info. I was using later versions of the apache classes (commons-codec-1.6, httpclient-4.2, httpcore-4.2) when I revereted to using the recommended classes (commons-codec-1.4, httpclient-4.1.2, httpcore-4.1.2) I recieve a "401.2 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration". "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept"

Comment: I am also facing the same problem and the marked answer is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Railo 4 now supports NTLM
    http://webonix.net/post/railo-can-do-ntlm-authentication
Railo 4.1 is required for IIS7 if it has multiple authentication providers